# Postgres(10.3) permission issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a PosgresQL(10.3) database. The database is created by user_owner, an has a complete structure but without rows data.

I want to access the database remotely.  With the user_owner I can access remotely the database with no issues.

But, I created a secondary user, user_remote. I want to use this user,instead of the user_owner because I will give him temporary remote access, and the user_owner is used for backend code.

For this user I give the privileges:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE name_db TO remote_user;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO remote_user;
```

When I try to connect with user_remote, remote , I can connect to the database, but If I try to do something else, like SELECT, I get an error:

```
[42501] ERROR: permission denied for relation table_name
```

If I connect in the database and give a table privileges, with:

GRANT ALL ON table_name TO user_remote;

works.

But, I have many tables, and what I wan to achieve:

1) give access to user_remote access to all tables in one/few steps, not table by table
2) I don't want user_remote to have all privileges, but just to do row operations(drop,update,insert)

Comment: is "auth" in public schema? was it created before granting?..

Comment: there is an initial database on the server, with tables but no data; I have an identical database as structure on my computer, and I want to push to the other one data; the databse on the server was create before the remote user

Comment: i use  show search_path and I got "$user", public

Comment: ah - you updated... try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public,auth TO remote_user;`

Comment: oid/(1 rows) - like I said is empty

Comment: so, auth is a table; the user is remote; if I grant table by table is working(see my question), but if I do on all tables is not working; I have many tables so this is why I want to do it once, and to understand what is the issue; when I said grant .. all tables  -echo grant; but it is not working

Comment: if auth is a table - how my select could return no rows?..

Comment: @VaoTsun ; after more tests on my side, I rephrased the question to be more clear; please take a look

Comment: all are failing

Comment: users_user,auth, account

Comment: the result of this please: `select oid::regclass from pg_class where relname = 'auth';`. of course you should run it as user that has permission - not remote

Comment: now, I have another issue to fix Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?